# How to create a persistent backwards ssh connection?

Tags: linux, ssh

Here's the scenario:

Linux server I own is in a datacenter with a public static IP.

A linux laptop I own is plugged in somewhere in the world.

Goal: I want the server to have an ssh connection to the laptop. From the linux server in the datacenter I want to somehow take over a ssh connection to the laptop to send remote commands to the laptop. Essentially I want the laptop to phone home but then the linux server has the ssh prompt. Since the server has no idea what IP the laptop is the connection has to initiate from the laptop back to the server with the static IP.

I'm thinking that netcat may be part of the solution but I'm not that familiar with it.
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Just set up a VPN and don't bother with anything complicated.

Comment: Why does server need to initialize ssh connection? Did not get that part.

Comment: I think this question belongs to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael already stated, VPN might be a solution for your problem. Otherwise you could use a cronjob on the laptop which makes the notebook tell the server its IP address. The server then could build a ssh connection to the laptop.